# Reverse a DECRYPT algorithm

Tags: javascript, cryptography, reverse

I'm having hard time reversing this algorithm:

```
decrypt_algorithm = function (text) {
  var parser = new TextParser(text);
  var decrypt_key = [16, 19, 17, 7, 20, 23, 13, 1, 24, 15, 6, 12, 0, 18, 21, 2, 9, 14, 3, 10, 5, 25, 8, 4, 22, 11];
  var text_size = parser.getSize();
  var text_size_without_last_part = text_size - 26;
  var output = [];
  if (text_size_without_last_part > 0) {
      for (var m = 0; m < text_size_without_last_part; m += 26) {
          var word_to_decrypt = [];
          for (var k = 0; k < 26; k++) {
              word_to_decrypt[k] = parser.readNextChar()
          }
          for (var k = 0; k < 26; k++) {
              output[m + k] = word_to_decrypt[decrypt_key[k]]
          }
      }
      var parser_position = parser.getPosition();
      var last_part_size = text_size - text_size_without_last_part - 1;
      if (last_part_text > 0) {
          for (var k = 0; k < last_part_size; k++) {
              output[text_size_without_last_part + k] = parser.readNextChar()
          }
      }
  }
  return output;
};
```

I don't have any reverse-engineering knowledge, so if you can point me to some resources which explains how to "reverse" a function, it will be really helpful.

I don't need the exact code as an answer, but some guides on how to reverse engineer it by my own is really appreciated.

**Edit 1:**

After taking a pause and thinking about the algorithm a bit, I understood the problem and it was easier than I thought:

`output[decrypt_key[k]] = word_to_decrypt[m + k]`

Changing this will revert the algorithm, solving the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by *reverse engineering*?  Do you just want to *reverse* the algorithm -- and write an *en*cryption function?  Because I would not apply the term "reverse engineering" to reading and understanding a block of code.

Comment: I want to reverse the algorithm, I thought it was called reverse engineering this too, I'll change the tag so!

Comment: @JimLewis: Sorry I thought it was reverse engineering this type of work too, I've changed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a simple permutation cipher. Essentially the `decrypt_key` is used to rearrange the output

```
output[m + k] = word_to_decrypt[decrypt_key[k]]


decrypt_key = [16, 19, 17, 7, 20, 23, 13, 1, 24, 15, 6, 12, 0, 18, 21, 2, 9, 14, 3, 10, 5, 25, 8, 4, 22, 11];
```

or, rearranged:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 16 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

The code

```
word_to_decrypt[decrypt_key[k]]
```

essentially takes the index into the code being "encrypted" and permutes it's words in 26 piece chunks.

You can think of it as just scrambling the words based on the "key", which tells you how it is being scrambled.

e.g,

```
decrypt_key[0] -> 16
decrypt_key[16] -> 9
```

which means that the first word(location 0) gets put at location 16 and the word at location 16 gets put at location 9.

Another term would be to call it a shuffle cipher. It shuffles up all the words, but in a very predictable manner.

As long as you know the `decypher_key` and the type of cipher you can recover the data quite easily just as you could with a deck of cards if you knew exactly how they were shuffled(since it's not truly random).

To make the inverse cipher you must create the opposite key. If location 0 went to 16 then that means location 16 would have to go to 0. Do this for each number in the array and form a new array called 'encrypt_key' and then you have a way to encrypt words that can be properly decrypted with the code you have given.

---

Lua code:

```
function printarray(arr) local s = '[' for k,v in pairs(arr) do s = s..tostring(v)..', '  end s = s:sub(1,-3)..']' return s end
function permute(arr, key) local newarr = {}; for i = 1, #key do newarr[i] = arr[key[i]] end return newarr end

letters = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
key = {5, 1, 3, 4, 2};
invkey = {}
newletters = permute(letters, key)
print('input:  '..printarray(letters))
print('key:    '..printarray(key))
print('output: '..printarray(newletters))


for i = 1, #key do
    for j = 1, #key do
        if i == key[j] then
            invkey[i] = j;
            break;
        end
    end
end;

newletters2 = permute(newletters, invkey)
print('\nInverse Permutation')
print('input:  '..printarray(newletters))
print('key:    '..printarray(invkey))
print('output: '..printarray(newletters2))
```

output:

```
input:  [a, b, c, d, e]
key:    [5, 1, 3, 4, 2]
output: [e, a, c, d, b]

Inverse Permutation
input:  [e, a, c, d, b]
key:    [2, 5, 3, 4, 1]
output: [a, b, c, d, e]
```

Comment: This is the same point where am I. However swapping all keys in the decrypt_key will result in an array like this: [0,1,2,3,4,5...], like your rearranged array. This is why I couldn't find the reverse key. Also as Dai states, symmetrical key doesn't mean that the same algorithm have been used to encrypt the message (even if I must say it looks so), but maybe a different one has been used.

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL I think you are not thinking about it hard enough. You must write the inverse permutation: I will start it off: `encrypt_key = [12, 7, 18, ...]`. The rearranged array is not the inverse but the result of the composition: decrypt_key[encrypt_key[k]]. k = 0 ==> decrypt_key[12] = 0. k = 1 =>> decrypt_key[7] = 1, etc... But `word_to_encrypt[encrypt_key[k]]` will give an permutation of the words and then when `word_to_decrypt[decrypt_key[k]]` will apply the inverse permutation(which is not 0 1 2 3 4 5 ...).

Comment: I simply rearranged the keys from lowest to highest so you could see that it is a permutation(there are no "gaps"). That is, if we think of k as going from 0 to 25 then decrypt_key simply makes it "out of order" but we still go from 0 to 25(just not 0 1 2 3 4 ... but 16 19 17 7 ....).

Comment: The problem is not really about reverse engineering but that of indexing. You seem to have a hard time understanding how to index an array... So my suggestion would be to try and simplify the problem to a simple array(remove all the encryption context since it is not important). If you have an array var a = new array[10] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}. Can you shuffle/permute it deterministically?

Comment: Yea but it would look like the code above: `var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; var key = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]; var result = []; for (var i = 0;i < key.length; ++i) { result[i] = array[key[i]]; }` That's the shortest way I can think about at the moment, but definitely is the same as the code above.

Comment: Yeah, so the array after execution is 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0. Now, you have chosen a symmetric key so that if you run the code on itself again you'll end up with the original array. If you would have chosen, say, 5 2 6 4 9 8 3 1 7 0 then the the key to decrypt it would not be the same. e.g., our "encrypted" array is 5 2 6 4 8 9 3 1 7 0. Then our decrypted_key must be 9 7 1 6 3 0 2 8 4 5. It is not the same key. When we apply the key to the array we end up with our original array back. You must make sure you keep the data separate from the key's(the indexers). You can use letters for data...

Comment: Mhhh thanks, I'm working on it. Give me some time, I'll answer again tomorrow, now it's really late. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm trying to brute force the key... but you know, 26 permutations are really too much for PCs too...

Comment: Thanks, I marked your as answer, the key looks symmetrical as you stated and you can see how I "reverted" the algorithm in the edit. Thanks again!

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL: yes, 26 letters has 26! ways to permutate. Again, you are making it way too difficult. If a key takes an index k to j then you just need to find how to go from the index j to k. I will give a simple example on 5 letters: (note, use a new line for each line, copy and paste into a text editor to view it better)


a b c d e <- data;
5 1 3 4 2 <- permutation;
b e c d a <- result;

inverse permutation:
b e c d a <- data;
2 5 3 4 1 <- inverse permutation;
a b c d e <- result;

Comment: I did not use some brute force approach to find the inverse permutation but simply "read" it off. I know that b is the second element so under b we have 2. I know e is the 5th element, c the 3rd, d the 4th and a the first.

Comment: a b c d e <- data;
5 1 3 4 2 <- permutation;
2 5 3 4 1 <- inverse permutation;
1 2 3 4 5 <- composite permutation;
a b c d e <- result;

Comment: Algorithm: Find inverse of [5 1 3 4 2]: Start from left to right: find position of 1, it is 2, find position of 2, it is 5, find position of 3 it is 3, find position of 4, it is 4, find position of 5, it is 1. This can be done with in O(n^2) using 2 for loops. for i=1 to n, for j = i to n if i == perm(j) then invperm[i] = j end end (or something like that)

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL: I've added some lua code that demonstrates the algorithm.

Comment: That's interesting, infact the code is giving me some troubles when I'm over 26 letters, I'm checking your lua code and try to solve my issue. I'll keep you updated

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL I'm not sure what you mean but your key length has to be the same length as your data or you have to "wrap" your index so you don't access elements or keys outside the length.

Comment: Nevermind, I just discovered I created a small bug inside my code, I'll let you know in an hour (I hope so)

Comment: Solved the issue, it was connected with the fact that I saved the encrypted file again with windows line endings while os x were used.

Comment: Yea, everything working correctly. I'm breathing again, these 2 days were hard. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL lol np... just make sure you use your knew found knowledge for good ;)

Comment: I know it looks "bad" when you decrypt something... but really, I used it to change a configuration file to locate some files in a different folder instead of the default one, it's really a stupid thing (notice that the file are the same, just I moved those for organization problems).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to reverse-engineer it: you already have the JavaScript source code. The algorithm looks simple enough (just two nested loops) - just stepping through it with a debugger should reveal how the "key" relates to any given input.

The algorithm looks symmetrical, so once you understand what they key does (it looks like it just shuffles characters around in a string according to the key), then you can derive the encryption function.

Comment: I thought too the key was symmetrical, however I tried re applying the key on a decrypted file and, however, I get a completely different encrypted file (notice that I have both an encrypted and encrypted file)

Comment: How did you "apply the key" to a decrypted file? Symmetrical encryption doesn't mean running the same function twice will flip between clear and ciphertext (unlike XORing), it just means that the same key can be used for both, although the encryption and decryption algorithms themselves will be different.

Comment: Mhhh... That's important, I have to work on a different algorithm... At least I won't waste other time on it. Thanks a lot for this suggestion.